# Loading extension apc for php5.4.6

Tags: php, apc

I'm afraid I put quite a mess on my development computer and I could use some help. Basically, I had php5.3.2 on ubuntu installed with apt-get package with apc loaded as a dynamic extension.

Today, I decided to upgrade to php5.4.6 using this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5. So, I run now php5.4.6 but apc won't load anymore.

So I did

```
pecl uninstall apc
```

then

```
pecl install apc-3.1.13
```

to make sure I got a version of apc compatible with php5.4.

Everythin seems to go well but the extension still won't load. It does not show on a phpinfo(). I added extension=apc.so in php.ini of course.

I think I found the origin of the problem but I don't know how to fix it:

According to my phpinfo():

```
PHP API                 20100412
PHP Extension           20100525
Zend Extension          220100525
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build     API20100525,NTS
```

When I do, pecl install apc, I got:

```
54 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

As a result apc.so will be installed in /usr/lib/php5/20090626 instead of /usr/lib/php5/20100525.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a way to fix that. A simple

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This not solves the problem. I have compiled PHP 5.4 and cant get APC loaded. your answer install php5-common and php5-fpm (another version of PHP)

Comment: I haven't compiled PHP 5.4 on my own but used the ppa mentionned above

Answer (score 0):

Just change the API version in zend_modules.h in your php binary source to the PHP extension API number which is indicates in phpinfo().

For example if the php extension API in phpinfo() is 20100525, you must change the API number in zend_modules.h file to 20100525 and then recompile your project.